# how to build good python web application

Tags: python, web-applications

i never worked with web programming and 
i've been asked lately to write a web-based software to manage assets and tasks. to be used   by more than 900 persons 
what are the recommended modules , frameworks , libraries for this task.
and it will be highly appreciated if you guyz recommend some books and articles that might help me. thanks in advance

Comment: What does "guyz" mean?  Why are there no capital letters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/). I would say it is the most comprehensive and easy to use python web framework.

They have a [book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/) and [tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) as well.

You might also like to visit [Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) about web frameworks for more suggestions. But still, I highly recommend Django.

Comment: +1 I'm currently working on a Django web app using Piston for the API layer: http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home

Comment: Another +1 for Django.  The documentation quality makes this an obvious choice for anybody new to web development.  Take the time to read it and understand it.

Answer (score 2):

I've really enjoyed working with [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) in my project. Django had a little more of a CMS feel than I needed.  As a Python novice, CherryPy was very approachable to me. After several months of working with it, I often find interesting ways to use and extend it. Not sure how good a match it might be for your project, but it's at least worth checking out as an alternative to Django.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/) for a while now and I highly recommend it.  Before using it I evaluated Django as well.  I found Pylons was a better fit due to how easy it was to customize and fit into my work flow.  Django seemed to be great for quickly starting projects, but I felt it was tough to make more complicated tasks work.  I've developed a task/inventory/contact management system with Pylons and I've been nothing but amazed with how quickly it's allowed me to develop and deploy.

Answer (score 1):

let's just get all the frameworks mentioned again.

[Turbogears](http://turbogears.org/)

[bfg](http://bfg.repoze.org)

[webob](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2010/03/12/a-webob-app-example/)

[web2py](http://web2py.com)

[zope](http://zope.org)

[grok](http://grok.zope.org)

etc etc etc....

Comment: at the time I wrote this someone had already mentioned pylons. I was strictly listing the rest. I happen to like pylons a lot only slightly less than bfg.

Answer (score 0):

I've never built web application with python-based framework but if I had to I would try [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)
I know people who worked with it and were very satisfied

Answer (score 0):

[Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) is a great place to start since it is the most widely used web framework for Python. You could also look at [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) which is build off of Django. Pinax is typically used for rapid development. Its templates are great for that. [Web.py](http://webpy.org/) is also another great Python web framework worth looking in to.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it but one of my co-workers has used the [Python Google Data API](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) and has said good things. Not positive of everything it can do but it might be helpful to you.